# DomPDF can't find image with direct URL to my own server, but can with URLS to any other server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, server, dompdf

I have laravel app that uses DomPDF to generate PDFs and i have a problem, that DomPDF cant find and therefor doesn't display images in pdfs.

It looks like this:

[image]

There definitely **isn't any problem** with the code of my app, because when i had this app on shared hosting server, everything worked fine. That's why i can't post any code snippet here.

I migrated to VPS, setup my server and i can't find the reason why DomPDF can't find images.

My app generates direct img URLs for DomPDF (eg.: https://example.com/img/img.png) and these can't be accessed by DomPDF, **but when i link image from any other domain, it works fine.**

I'm 99% sure problem is in some settings on my server.

-my server is running on ubuntu 22, apache2, php8.1

Here is my servers phpinfo: https://collama.com/phpinfo.php

One more weird behaviour i found, that lets me to belive that something on my server is blocking DomPDF is:
When i restart my server and immediately generate PDF, it somehow works fine.
But after like a minute or two it stops working again.
That's why i belive that something starts on my server that starts this blocking.
But i have no idea what.

I read literally every dompdf post here on stackoverflow but still can't find the solution, mostly because every question talks about code problem and not server settings.

Comment: Have you checked?
1. Open your image in a new tab.
2. Check file image directory permission

If still facing the issue, try to decode your image on base64 and then apply. 
may helps you.